# How to pass props on click (v-data-table)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using v-data-table in my app, and having now problem with passing props on click.

I can props in with extra slot. But I want click the whole row for open the dialog with prop `item`:

```
<template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
    <div><v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="openInDialog(item)"> mdi-arrow-right </v-icon></div>
</template>
```

This below is working for just firing the function, but how can I pass one item in that function?:

```
<v-data-table
    @click:row="openEquipmentInDialog()"
    style="cursor: pointer"
></v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click item is the first parameter of the event handler :

```
<v-data-table
@click:row="openEquipmentInDialog"
style="cursor: pointer"
></v-data-table>
```

method :

```
openEquipmentInDialog(item){
//
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It somehow automatically passing the if not using ```()``` tags. It works.